# Create a user in AAD B2C

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm working on an SPA/Web API app and using AAD B2C for user authentification.

As a feature, I want to let the user create users accounts from the app UI and I have planned to use the Microsoft Graph API to achieve this (POST /users).

However, I have read that to authenticate on this API we had to user client credentials workflow (using client secret) and I don't find this convenient, because the client_secret will expire.

Do you have any idea on how to improve the process of using Microsoft Graph API ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** that: If you don't want to use client secret for authentication, then you can try using certificate-based authentication.

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted Application permissions**:

[image]

Create an  **Self-Signed**  certificate using PowerShell:

```bash
$certname = "certname"    
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$certname" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -HashAlgorithm SHA256
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:/test/$certname.cer"
```

[image]

Export the  certificate to  **`.pfx`**:

```bash
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -Force -AsPlainText 
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:/test/$certname.pfx" -Password $mypwd
```

[image]

I uploaded the **`.cer`** certificate in the Azure AD Application:

[image]

**To create Azure AD B2C user, I used the below code:**

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Users\\rukmini\\testrukkp.pfx", "xxxx");

IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create("ClientAppID")
    .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID"))
    .Build();

string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
AuthenticationResult authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();


var user = new
{
    accountEnabled = true,
    displayName = "Adele Vance",
    mailNickname = "AdeleV",
    userPrincipalName = "AdeleV@b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com",
    passwordProfile = new
    {
        forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        password = "Password"
    }
};


var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(user);
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users", content);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine("User created successfully.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error creating user: " + await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

[image]

**The user created successfully like below:**

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can create client secret with custom expiry date:

[image]

Comment: thank you for you quick answer!
But certificates also expires, no ?

Comment: But certificates are more secure than client secret

Comment: yes, of course! Is there any alternative that does not expire ? I mean, the user will have to add new users in aad b2c via the app and with the solution of secret/certificate, I would have to manage the refresh "manually". So, it could happen that if I do not refresh the secret/certificate, the user could not add new aad b2c user. In that kind of case, how is it done usually ?

Comment: AFAIK, certificates and secrets expire at a certain point. Hence as an workaround set custom expiry date with limit of 2 years.

Comment: are managed identities a posssible workaround ? i've read somewhere that you cannot use them with aad b2c. Do you know more ? 
thanks for your previous answers

Comment: my question was about improving the process of using Microsoft Graph API, as I have already managed to use user credentials workflow... My question is not yet answered...

Comment: You can also try using managed identities by granting permissions to it and try

Comment: but as this post says, it is not possible : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236266/use-managed-identity-with-azure-b2c-directly-or-with-keyvault ... any idea ?

Comment: Azure AD B2C doesn't support managed identity. Hence you can create client secret by setting custom expiry date or use certificates as an workaround.

Comment: I know this is possible, but with the client secret/certificates, I would have to check whether they are expired or not. Is it ok to do so in production mode ? My need is to perform CRUD operations on Graph API via my SPA, is there a common way to call this API ? thank you for your time